# Is there a way to add Startswith in searchTerm (Apache Camel Mail Component)

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I am trying to poll email server to read emails with a specific subject.

Camel Mail Component documentation does have an example that explains to use SearchTerm to filter subjects containing a string. However, I am looking for a way to read emails having subject startWith specific string.

I am new to Camel route and trying to use this:

```
<route>
  <from uri="imaps://mymailseerver? 
     username=foo&password=secret&searchTerm.subject=Camel"/>
  <to uri="bean:myBean"/>
</route>
```

I wan to change this filter searchTerm.subject=Camel and add something like searchTerm.subjectStartsWith = Ca.

Comment: Any specific coding/technical challenges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those search term from the uri, matches on contains, and not starts with. So you cannot do this like that, but you can implement your own search term class where you can add the starts with logic, see the doc with the example where we refer to a custom implementation using the `#` syntax

https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/mail-component.html#_using_custom_searchterm